# Why launching does it random?

Tags: java

When i run this program sometimes shows me all buttons, but sometimes only 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or even just 1.. why is that??
I really do not get it. There should always be 6 buttons, but it doesnt show them. Is there any logical reason?

```js
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class testnet
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Knjigarna");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(800,200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Prikazi vse");
        panel.add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener (new Action1());

        JButton button2 = new JButton("Prikazi knjigo");
        panel.add(button2);
        button2.addActionListener (new Action2());

        JButton button3 = new JButton("Dodaj knjigo");
        panel.add(button3);
        button3.addActionListener (new Action3());

        JButton button4 = new JButton("Brisi knjigo");
        panel.add(button4);
        button4.addActionListener (new Action4());

        JButton button5 = new JButton("Uredi knjigo");
        panel.add(button5);
        button5.addActionListener (new Action5());

        JButton button6 = new JButton("Izhod");
        panel.add(button6);
        button6.addActionListener (new Action6());
    }

    static class Action1 implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
        {     
            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Pikaz vseh knjig");
            frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame2.setSize(500,800);
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Seznam vseh knjig:");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JTextField text1=new JTextField("Naslov: ");
            JTextField text2=new JTextField("Avtor: ");
            frame2.add(panel);
            panel.add(label);  
            panel.add(text1);
            panel.add(text2);
        }
    }

    static class Action2 implements ActionListener
    {        
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
        {     
            JFrame frame3 = new JFrame("Prikaz knjige");
            frame3.setVisible(true);
            frame3.setSize(600,300);

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Vpisi naslov knjige:");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            frame3.add(panel);
            panel.add(label);
        }
    }
    static class Action3 implements ActionListener
    {        
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
        {     
            JFrame frame4 = new JFrame("Dodajanje knjige");
            frame4.setVisible(true);
            frame4.setSize(600,300);

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Vpisi podtke o knjigi");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            frame4.add(panel);
            panel.add(label);
        }
    }   

    static class Action4 implements ActionListener
    {        
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
        {     
            JFrame frame5 = new JFrame("Brisanje knjige");
            frame5.setVisible(true);
            frame5.setSize(600,300);

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Vpisi naslov knjige, ki jo zelis brisati");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            frame5.add(panel);
            panel.add(label);
        }
    }   

    static class Action5 implements ActionListener
    {        
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
        {     
            JFrame frame6 = new JFrame("Urejanje knjige");
            frame6.setVisible(true);
            frame6.setSize(600,300);

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Vpisi naslov knjige, ki jo zelis urejati");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            frame6.add(panel);
            panel.add(label);
        }
    }   

    static class Action6 implements ActionListener
    {        
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
        {     
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I have run your code, and for me, there are always 6 buttons. It would seem that your code is ok. Sorry this isn't too helpful! Incidentally, the accepted convention is that your class name should start with an upper case letter. "Testnet" - not that it would help you solve this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

try something with layout. `JFrame` and or remove managed by inside with a content pane. content pane default layout is `BorderLayout`. so you need to try border layout stuff.
or you can try this code in you main method

```
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

this will add component by one by one.

for more about layout you can get in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Comment: The OP is adding the buttons to a Panel... And default layout of a panel is `FlowLayout`

Answer (score 0):

This is just a fix and not really an explanation of why the problem is occurring.

Call `frame.revalidate()` after adding all the buttons.

From the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)),

**public Component add(Component comp)**

> This method
>   changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the
>   component hierarchy. If the container has already been displayed, the
>   hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to display the added
>   component.